# android:elevation doesn't work with BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android

I have a `ListView` and a `BottomNavigationView`. I want the `ListView` to the on top of `BottomNavigationView`. In other words, the user can only see `ListView`, he/she cannot find `BottomNavigationView`. I tried using `android:elevation` on `ListView` to achieve this. Here is my code.

## activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/list_view"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_view"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

## menu/bottom_nav_view

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="Find"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"/>
</menu>
```

## drawable-v24/ic_search.xml

```xml
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
  <path
      android:fillColor="#A7A7A7"
      android:pathData="M15.5,14h-0.79l-0.28,-0.27C15.41,12.59 16,11.11 16,9.5 16,5.91 13.09,3 9.5,3S3,5.91 3,9.5 5.91,16 9.5,16c1.61,0 3.09,-0.59 4.23,-1.57l0.27,0.28v0.79l5,4.99L20.49,19l-4.99,-5zM9.5,14C7.01,14 5,11.99 5,9.5S7.01,5 9.5,5 14,7.01 14,9.5 11.99,14 9.5,14z"/>
</vector>
```

## MainActivity.java

```java
package com.body.elevationtest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

However, it didn't work. The result is as follows.

[image: Result]

Why? How to make it work? By the way, I don't want to use `android:visibility` on `BottomNavigationView` to make it work.

Comment: Did you try FrameLayout?

Comment: Did you try place the ListView below the BottomNavigationView in you xml?

Comment: @shb Haven't, currently I'm just trying to make it work with `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: @arsalanelec Tried, doesn't work. The result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

the `ListView` should have elevation more than **8dp**
or equals to **8dp** if your View element placed lower than your `ButtomNavigationView`.
**Or** you can change your `ButtomNavigationView` elevation **app:elevation** to a value lower than your `ListView`

Answer (score 0):

You should add `background` attribute along with `elevation` else it wont show the shadow.

```
  android:background="#FFF"
  android:elevation="2dp"
```

To make list view on top of bottomnavigationview, you can use frame layout, make the list match parent in both width and height, the set the gravity of bottomnavigationview to bottom

Comment: Thanks, but I have already added `android:background` in my `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: No, you haven't added those attributes to bottomnavigationview

Comment: I just added it to `BottomNavigationView`. I can see that the shadow is shown. But my problem is not that. My problem is that I want to place `ListView` on top of `BottomNavigationView` but I cannot do that.

Comment: Simply use a frame layout